# Spark Java - Problem with request.session(false)

Tags: java, spark-java

Premise: I'm speaking about Per Wendel's Spark Java web framework not about Apache Spark.

The problem I faced off is that **sometimes** the method `request.session(false)` returns null even if the session is just created.
I know that method returns null if session doesn't exist but, as I said, session should exists because the method above is called few seconds after the method `request.session()` that create the new session.

I repeat: this happens sometimes.

This is a code snippet example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //some operations

    get("/hello", (req, res) -> {
        Session session = req.session();
        //other stuffs
    }):

    post("/action", (req, res) -> {
        //session sometimes is null
        Session session = req.session(false);

        //other stuffs
    });
}
```

Can session created by `request.session(true)` become soon invalid? If yes, why?
I'd like to understand which causes can invalidate the session, apart from timeout expiration or an explicit call to `session.invalidate()`.

Comment: The Session is just available in the scope

Comment: Sorry, I'don't understand. I know, the session should be available in the scope. But  for some reason, sometimes, it isn't. So when I call a method on the session instance I get a NullPointerException. If can help I noticed that if I type, after the this behavior, the /hello URI the session is not lost because req.session() return the old session, so it doesn't create a new one.